# Verification: Hessian of the following composition.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

I was hoping that someone could verify the steps of computing a Hessian matrix.

I have the following function, $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$,

$$F({\bf x}) = \sum_{i=1}^mf(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))$$

where each $A_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n_i}$ translates ${\bf x}$ into some subvector of ${\bf x}$, for example, $A_1^T{\bf x} = (x_1,x_5,x_6,x_{10})$ (Notice that $A_i$ just consists of zeros and ones). Other functions are defined as $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^{n_i}\to\mathbb{R}$.

I want to determine the Hessian, denoted $\nabla^2_{{\bf x}} F({\bf x})$.

***Gradient***

I have computed the gradient to be
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\bf x}F({\bf x}) &= \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial}{\partial {\bf x}}f(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))
\end{align*}
which component-wise is
\begin{align*}
[\nabla_{\bf x}F({\bf x})]_k&= \sum_{i=1}^mf'(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{\partial g({\bf v})}{\partial v_j}\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_k}\\
\end{align*}
where ${\bf v} = A_i^T{\bf x}$.

Is the work so far correct? It seems to be dimensionally consistent. The term, $\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial [A_i^T{\bf x}]_j}{\partial x_k}$, can be simplified to read
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial [A_i^T{\bf x}]_j}{\partial x_k} = [A_i{\bf e}_j]_k
\end{align*} 
where ${\bf e}_j\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a zero column vector with a $1$ in the $j^{th}$ position.

***Hessian***

To start, the Hessian is given by the expression

\begin{align*}
\nabla^2_{\bf x}F({\bf x}) &= \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial^2}{\partial {\bf x}^2}f(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))
\end{align*}

which component-wise, differentiating the gradient, becomes

\begin{align*}
[\nabla^2_{\bf x}F({\bf x})]_{kl}&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_l}\sum_{i=1}^mf'(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{\partial g({\bf v})}{\partial v_j}[A_i{\bf e}_j]_k\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial f'(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))}{\partial x_l}\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{\partial g({\bf v})}{\partial v_j}[A_i{\bf e}_j]_k\\
&\qquad\qquad+ \sum_{i=1}^mf'(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_l}\left[\frac{\partial g({\bf v})}{\partial v_j}[A_i{\bf e}_j]_k\right].
\end{align*}

Notice that the term $\frac{\partial g({\bf v})}{\partial v_j}$ is a function of ${\bf x}$. So, applying the product rule/chain rule, we obtain
\begin{align*}
[\nabla^2_{\bf x}F({\bf x})]_{kl}&= \sum_{i=1}^mf''(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{\partial g({\bf v})}{\partial v_j}[A_i{\bf e}_j]_k\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{\partial g({\bf v})}{\partial v_j}[A_i{\bf e}_j]_l\right)\\
&\qquad+\sum_{i=1}^mf'(g(A_i^T{\bf x}))\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{\partial^2 g({\bf v})}{\partial x_l\partial v_j}[A_i{\bf e}_j]_k
\end{align*}
where the term $\frac{\partial^2 g({\bf v})}{\partial x_l\partial v_j}$ is only non-zero if $[A_i^T{\bf x}]_j = x_l$.

Is the above work correct? Is there any way to verify its correctness other than rechecking each step?